# Why am I getting E2029 Declaration expected but 'FINALIZATION' found

Tags: delphi

I don't see any syntax error, my code compiles clean without the finalization section. Here is the last few lines of the unit.

```
function boolAsTF(b:boolean): string; inline;
begin
  if b then result := 'T' else result := 'F';
end;

finalization
  SyncMgr.Free;
end.
```

Comment: Have you tried putting an empty Initialization section ahead of the finalization one?

Comment: This is a [trivial error](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Programs_and_Units#The_Finalization_Section). The fake code in v1 made this a terrible question; even the current version falls short of an MCVE.

Comment: Yes, it is a trivial error, but if you made it, it was hard to find an answer -- I never noticed that finalization required initialization when I started coding in Delphi years ago and found it difficult to figure out when I made the mistake. That is specifically the only reason I documented it here. Just so Google will find the answer when you hit the error condition.

Comment: @CraigYoung -- Just thought to check, already Google shows me as this question as the first hit when seaching for "E2029 Declaration expected but 'FINALIZATION' found"  -- so it would be nice if this were not down-voted, etc. out of existence. See the prior comment too.

Comment: @Gary Yes the title obviously makes this searchable; the only reason I didn't vote to close. As for "hard to find the answer": I really don't see how, but do acknowledge I approach problem solving differently to many people. 1) Msg clearly indicates 'surprise' finalization is wrong. 2) This 'special pairing' concept is not unique/obscure: `interface->implementation` even `begin/end` or `()` 3) Find existing examples in code/otherwise - all would have initialization. 4) RTFM - as above, it's clearly stated. _**Nutshell:** If mistake is made: there are many obvious, accessible clues to fix it._

Comment: I also acknowledge some error messages can be a little difficult to decipher. (Especially for beginner programmers.) Alas compilers can't read people's minds to say: "Aah, I see what you're trying. It's wrong because…". Compilers use state machines. In each state there's a small number things that are expected. If you code anything that's ***not*** expected, it's an error. E.g. Replace `finalization` with almost anything else and you get a similar error. _It expects things like `type`, `function`, `initialization`, `{`._

Comment: @CraigYoung -- Thanks. Here's the thing I've been programming fulltime for about 40 years. Yet when I hit this the first time (10 years ago?) it was hard for me. I did not think of initialization/finalization like a begin end pair, I thought of them as simply 2 sections, like a destructor without a constructor (often a poor idea), so it was obscure to me years ago. Nothing suggested to me that finalization by itself would a bad thing - that is why it was obscure, examples that showed both meant nothing, I needed no initialization. Programming is hard because of weird things sometimes.

Comment: constructor/destructor are nothing like "sections". Rather compare `implementation` without `interface`. Yes, the error message is more informative. It's still not allowed. There's nothing bad about finalization by itself, it's just not allowed (and would be trivial to support). There's also nothing inherently bad about an implementation by itself (with initialization section the only thing using what's defined). Whether they _should_ be allowed for the rare cases they're desired is a language design question. But at one word for an **explicitly empty section**, why bother?

Comment: @Gary I'll reiterate. If you found the error message confusing, it would be more so for beginners. So the question does have its place. But because the alleged MCVE is not *complete* it's a poor question. Especially when you remember that these kinds of errors fundamentally depend on context: the earlier code; what state the compiler is in; and what it's expecting. A good MCVE also shouldn't clutter with other mistakes that are irrelevant to the question; they just add confusion. E.g. using undeclared `SyncMgr`.

Answer (score 7):

**If you use a finalization section, you must also use an initialization section.**

I accidentally hit this again, and remember this being hard to figure out the first time. So I thought I would document it here to help the next guy.

Kudos to MartynA who answered in a comment about as fast I I did when I knew I was going to answer it immediately.